# Error API Facebook - Angular 2 and Ionic 2

Tags: facebook, typescript, facebook-graph-api, ionic2, angular2-services

I'm working with the facebook API and I need to get the profile data to save it in a database. The code returns fine, but when I try to access the data it shows me error because they are null.

This is my code:

```
this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
      .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
        token = res.authResponse.accessToken;
        userId = res.authResponse.userID;

        if (res.status == 'connected') {
          this.fb.api('/' + res.authResponse.userID + '?fields=id,first_name,last_name,gender, email,birthday', [],
            function onSuccess(result) {
              var name = JSON.stringify(result.first_name);   
              this.register(name);           
            },
            function onError(error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
          console.log('Not logged in');
        }
      }).catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));
```

When I try to call the `register` method it generates error because the method does not exist, but this is not true. I also tried to save the result of `name` to a global variable but when it is to be assigned it shows that it can not assign the variable, ie as if the global variable was not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change

```
function onSuccess(result) {
   var name = JSON.stringify(result.first_name);   
   this.register(name);           
},
function onError(error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

for

```
(result) => {
   var name = JSON.stringify(result.first_name);   
   this.register(name);           
},
(error) => {
   console.log(error);
});
```